# How to strip single quotes from a varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application that passes data to an sql variable called `@inputvar`. The application passes the data as a string. The stored procedure declares the variable `@inputvar` as `varchar`. The problem is, the data is of the format `'12,13,15'`. because of a where clause in the stored procedure, i am getting an error saying that `conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int`

The where cause is:

```
select * 
from table 
where ID in (@inputvar)
```

I have tried stripping the quotes: `replace(@inputvar,'''','')` and I have tried converting the variable to an int: `cast(@inputvar as int)`, but both attempts failed

Comment: This question again?    http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this; you can use dynamic query to handle your scenario

```
DECLARE @inputvar varchar(10)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
set @inputvar = '12,13,15'

set @sql = 'select * from table where ID in (' + REPLACE(@inputvar, '''','') + ')'
EXEC @sql
```